# Django and Matplotlib: signal only works in main thread

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

In `views.py` of my Django project, at a certain point in the code, I want to display a graph plot on the server to visualise in real-time the user input. So, I created another file `plotter.py` in the same folder as `views.py`, with the following content to display a simple graph:

import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot

```
def plot():
    N = 50
    x = numpy.random.rand(N)
    y = numpy.random.rand(N)
    colors = numpy.random.rand(N)
    area = numpy.pi * (15 * numpy.random.rand(N))**2
    matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
    matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Then, in `views.py`, I `import plotter`, and then at my desired point in the file, I have `plotter.plot()`. However, this gives the following error:

```
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/teacher/
Django Version:     1.7
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

signal only works in main thread

Exception Location:     C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py in mainloop, line 150
Python Executable:  C:\Anaconda\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.8
```

How can I achieve this without causing such an error?

Comment: Not sure this is _really_ the way you want to do this. It would be better to have a REST interface or inter-process message passing and have your plotting gui code in it's own process.

Answer (score 7):

run your server as follows

```
python manage.py runserver --nothreading --noreload
```

Comment: This only disables threading in a development server. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-runserver-nothreading